Maximum size of a Hilbert/Monomial Basis
Hilbert Basis Theorem (Theorem 4, Page 77 in [1]) states that every ideal $I=<f_1,\cdots,f_s>\subseteq k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ has a generative set of finite size $t\geq 1$.
Can we bound $t$ as a function of $s$,  $n$ and/or the maximum total degree $d$?
The proof seems to reduce to Dickson's Lemma (Theorem 5 in Page 72): that every monomial ideal has a basis of finite size. Again, there is no clue about this size. From the proof of Dickson's Lemma it seems that $t$ is at most exponential in $d$. In Theorem 4 above $t$ is bounded by the size $m$ of the Groebner Basis of $I$, according to some order, so maybe my question can be reduced to "Suggest an upper bound on $m$, given the above (possibly non-Groebner) basis for $I$." The book give examples of computation time that is double exponential in $d$, but it is not clear if this implies that the size of the smallest Groebner basis is also double exponential in $d$..
It seems like a trivial or at least natural question. However, from Google, I could not find paper that analyzes the complexity of $t$ in terms of $s$ and $n$. I am probably missing something...
[1] -- Cox, D., Little, J., O'shea, D., & Sweedler, M. (1997). Ideals, varieties, and algorithms (Vol. 3). New York: Springer.

There is the trivial bound $t\leq s$, but that's sharp - consider $I=(x_1,\cdots,x_n)^m$ for any $m\geq 1$, for instance. I don't think there's really a ton to say here.

Thanks for this observation! I probably need to rephrase the question. Suppose that $s$ is infinity, or just too bad as an upper bound. Can we find better upper bounds using $d$ and $n$? Can we compute a tight bound via a Groebner basis of $I$ or some other method?
